# Javascript loop terminates partway through when accessing a prototype function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, prototype, javascript-objects

I'm writing a battle in JavaScript. The program will sometimes run, sometimes not. Sometimes it will loop 5-6 times before throwing an error.

The functions are Player, Weapon, Enemy, and BattleSimulation.
The functions on the prototypes are applyDamage, isAlive, attackWith, attack, createEnemies, createPlayers, run.

I'm getting practice using prototypes, but I'm not very clear on using them. There's an array of 5 players and 20 enemies.

I get this error after some loop iterations:

```
console.log("Your fighter is: " + myPlayer.name);
                                           ^
```

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Sometimes the error comes on a different part of the code. I want to check if the player is still alive before sending them into battle. Once they die, I don't want them going back into battle, so I check if they're alive using the function defined in Player.prototype.

```
    while (myPlayer.isAlive == false) {
      myPlayer = players[Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)];
    }
```

I sometimes get TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAlive' of undefined.

Can you help me figure out this prototype stuff and if I'm doing it correctly? Thank you!!!

The code:

```
function Player(name, weapons) {
 // Each player has a name, an initial health of 10, an 
 // initial strength of 2, and an array of weapons objects
  this.name = name;
  this.health = 10;
  this.strength = 2;
  this.weapons = weapons;
}

// applyDamage deals damage to the Player - takes an integer 
// input and subtracts that from the player's health
Player.prototype.applyDamage = function(damage) {
  console.log(damage + " damage applied!");
  // Subtract damage received from the player's health
  this.health -= damage;
  console.log(this.name + "\'s health is now " + this.health);
};

// isAlive checks if the player's health is >0. Returns true 
// if it is and false if not.
Player.prototype.isAlive = function() {
  if (this.health > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

// attackWith uses a random number between 7 and 0, selects 
// the weapon at that index, and returns the weapon
Player.prototype.attackWith = function() {
  let choice = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (7));
  return this.weapons[choice];
};


function Weapon(name) {
  // Each weapon has an assigned name and random damage level
  this.name = name;
  this.damage = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5); 
  //random number between 1 and 5
}

// attack checks if the fighters are dead, then applies damage 
// based on strength and weapon
Weapon.prototype.attack = function(player, enemy) {
  while (player.isAlive && enemy.isAlive) {
    // Calculate actual damage = 
    // strength of player * damage value of weapon
    let actualDamage = player.strength * this.damage;
    console.log("\n" + player.name + " attacks " + enemy.name 
+ "!");

    // Call the applyDamage function of the Enemy object and 
    // pass the actual damage value calculated
    enemy.applyDamage(actualDamage);
    console.log("Enemy health is " + enemy.health);

    // Call the isAlive function of the Enemy object. If the 
    // enemy is dead, exit.
    // If the enemy is not dead, call the attack function and 
    // pass it the player object.
    if (enemy.isAlive) {
      console.log("\n" + enemy.name + " attacks " 
                  + player.name + "!");
      enemy.attack(player);
    } else {
      return "enemyDead";
    }
  }
};


function Enemy() {
  // The default enemy has a name of Enemy, health of 5, and 
// strength of 2
  this.name = "Enemy";
  this.health = 5;
  this.strength = 2;
}

// applyDamage takes an integer input and subtracts that from 
// the enemy's health
Enemy.prototype.applyDamage = function(damage) {
  console.log(this.name + " is hit with " + damage 
              + " damage.");
  this.health -= damage;
};

// isAlive checks if the enemy's health is greater than 0. 
// Returns true if it is and false if not.
Enemy.prototype.isAlive = function() {
  if (this.health > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

// attack takes a player input and calls the applyDamage of 
// the player using enemy's strength as input
Enemy.prototype.attack = function(player) {
  //console.log("\n" + this.name + " attacks!");
  player.applyDamage(this.strength);
};

function BattleSimulation() {
  // The battle simulation has an array of players and enemies
  this.players = [];
  this.enemies = [];
}

// createEnemies uses a loop to create 20 Enemy instances and 
// populate the Enemies array property
BattleSimulation.prototype.createEnemies = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    this.enemies.push(new Enemy());
  }
};

// createPlayers creates 8 weapons objects and 5 player 
// instances.
BattleSimulation.prototype.createPlayers = function() {
  // Create 8 weapons objects in weaponsCache
  var w1 = new Weapon('Marshmallows');
  var w2 = new Weapon('Snowflakes');
  var w3 = new Weapon('The love you didn\'t get as a child');
  var w4 = new Weapon('Machine guns');
  var w5 = new Weapon('Paper cuts');
  var w6 = new Weapon('A really tough personal trainer');
  var w7 = new Weapon('Stepping on a lego');
  var w8 = new Weapon('Very short vampires');
  var weaponsCache = [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8];

  // Create 5 player instances and add to the players array
  var p1 = new Player('Kate', weaponsCache);
  var p2 = new Player('Charming Male Companion', weaponsCache);
  var p3 = new Player('Iron Professor', weaponsCache);
  var p4 = new Player('Golden Army Captain', weaponsCache);
  var p5 = new Player('Lieutenant Hadrian', weaponsCache);
  this.players = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5];
  return this.players;

};

// run the battle
BattleSimulation.prototype.run = function() {
  console.log("Simulating Battle");

  // Create enemies
  var enemies = this.createEnemies();

  // Create players
  var players = this.createPlayers();

  var enemyBodyCount = 0;
  var playerBodyCount = 0;

  // Until all the players are dead or all the enemies die
  do {
    // Select random player
    var myPlayer = players[Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)];

    // Pick a new player if dead
    while (myPlayer.isAlive) {
      myPlayer = players[Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)];
    }

        console.log("\nNew fight!");
    console.log("Your fighter is: " + myPlayer.name);

    // Select a random enemy
    var myEnemy = this.enemies[Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20)];

    // Check if the enemy selected is alive. Pick a new enemy if dead.
    while (myEnemy.isAlive==false) {
      myEnemy = this.enemies[Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20)];
    }

    console.log("Your enemy is: " + myEnemy.name + ", with " + myEnemy.health + " health");

    // Call the attackWith method on the player to get a weapon to attack with
    var myWeapon = myPlayer.attackWith();
    console.log("Your weapon is: " + myWeapon.name);

    // Call the attack method on the weapon and pass it the current player and current enemy
    var whosDead = myWeapon.attack(myPlayer, myEnemy);

    if (whosDead == "enemyDead") {
        enemyBodyCount++;
    } else {
        playerBodyCount++;
    }

  //  let enemyBodyCount = 0;
  // for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  //    if (enemies[i].isAlive <= 0) {
  //      enemyBodyCount++;
  //      console.log(enemyBodyCount);
  //    }
  //  }
  //    let playerBodyCount = 0;
  //   for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  //    if (this.players[i].isAlive <= 0) {
  //      console.log(players[i]);
  //      playerBodyCount++;
  //      console.log(playerBodyCount);
  //    }
  //  }*/

    if (playerBodyCount >= 6) {
      console.log("\nSorry, Scarlett Byte has defeated you and conquered the free world.");
    }
    if (enemyBodyCount >=20) {
      console.log("\nCongratulations, you have defeated Scarlett Byte");
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
 } while (playerBodyCount < 6 || enemyBodyCount < 21);

  //console.log(players);
  //console.log(enemies);
};

// Test program
var simulator = new BattleSimulation();
simulator.run();
```

Comment: `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)` is picking a number from 1 to 5.  If you want a number between 0 and players.length - 1, use `Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of your players array after you run this.createPlayers to make sure it's populated? The error seems to say that it is not.

Comment: Whoa I think that's it. I was creating random numbers 1-5 for another part of the code and reused that code, forgetting to change it back to 0-4. Thank you!!!